# Load part of web page in android webview

Tags: javascript, html, class, webview

I want to load part of web page inside my webview. I used javascript to hide some div classes but the problem is first it loads the page completely and then hide the div class, I am wondering if there is a way to load specific part of web page inside the webview or there is a method to first run javascript and then load the web page.
here is the code that i use to hide the div class:

```
public class main extends AppCompatActivity {

    String url = "the web page url";
    WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);

        new load_web.execute();

    }

    private class load_web extends AsyncTask < Void, Void, Void > {

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.samsung_webView);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                    webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " + "document.getElementsByClassName('header-container')[0].style.display='none'; " + "})()");

                }
            });
            webView.loadUrl(url);

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void...voids) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after some struggle, I found the solution. I should set the javascript code in the onLoadResource rather than the public void onPageFinished. the correct code is :

private class load_web extends AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onLoadResource(view, url);

                webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " + "document.getElementsByClassName('header-container')[0].style.display='none'; " + "})()");

            }
```